# LINQ left join doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I've got something wrong with a left join in LINQ.

My SQL query is working properly:

```sql
VoilierInscrit vi 
join Course co on vi.idCourse = co.Id_Course
join Epreuve ep on co.Id_Course = ep.idcourse
LEFT join Penalite pe on vi.Id_VoilierInscrit = pe.VoilierInscrit
join Tps tp on ep.Id_Epreuve = tp.IDepreuve
where tp.IDvoilierInscrit = vi.Id_VoilierInscrit
ORDER BY Temps
```

The result ('Temps' and 'Duree' are TimeSpan) :

```
NumeroSerie      Temps       Duree
  KB48          00:05:00      NULL
  JY90          00:15:00     00:05:00
```

But when I'm doing it in LINQ, I get the following error: 
'The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.TimeSpan which is a non-nullable'

```
var resultat = from vi in db.VoilierInscrit
               from co in db.Course.Where(x => vi.idCourse == x.Id_Course)
               from ep in db.Epreuve.Where(x => co.Id_Course == x.idcourse)
               from pe in db.Penalite.Where(x => vi.Id_VoilierInscrit == x.VoilierInscrit)
               .DefaultIfEmpty()
               from tps in db.Tps.Where(x => ep.Id_Epreuve == x.IDepreuve)
               where tps.IDvoilierInscrit == vi.Id_VoilierInscrit

               select new
               {

                   temps = tps.Temps,
                   SerialNumber = vi.NumeroSerie,
                   duree = pe.Duree
               };
```

I really don't know where is the problem — my LINQ syntax seems to be correct.

Comment: Well, this first noticeable thing is that SQL query has 1 left outer join while the LINQ - 4.

Comment: And the second is that LINQ join to `Penatilte` (`x => ep.Id_Epreuve == x.idepreuve`) is different than the one used in SQL query.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you, i've rewrited my query and edited my post, now i've got an error 'seems to be a nice step though :
'The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.TimeSpan which is a non-nullable'

Comment: Use `duree = (DateTime?)pe.Duree` are you are done :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks a lot Ivan, i've learned a lot !! It works perfectly now ! Have a good day dude !